# Not able to create dynamic xpaths in python selenium for this website

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, chrome-automation-extension

Here is the website which I'm trying to automate for scraping data: [website link](https://www.carsales.com.au/cars/private/used/). I have to do the following:

1. select Location as Victoria, then region as Melbourne.
2. select Make as, say, Abarth. the will repeat for other makes.

I have tried static xpaths and also tried creating dynamic xpaths with my limited knowledge but still i am not able to do the task.

I use python selenium and automating google chrome.

Here is a snapshot of my wrong code for selection Abarth as make:

```
make_ele = WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@data-name="make"]'))).click()
select_abarth_ele = WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="multiselect-searchbox"]//input[@class, "border py-1 px-2 mb-1")]'))).send_keys("Abarth")
```

Comment: What's the problem you're facing now?Could you show your attempt?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA edited with my xpaths for make.

Comment: @HarshVardhan _...Not able to create dynamic xpaths in python selenium for this website..._ for which step?

Comment: @DebanjanB both the steps actually.

Comment: Please [edit the question](/posts/65196487/edit) to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xpaths has to be reviewed. Try this:

```
make_ele = WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[contains(text(),'Make')]'))).click()
select_abarth_ele = WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class,"multiselect-searchbox")]/input'))).send_keys("Abarth")
```

If you don't want to use *contains(text(),'text')* you can use also following relative path *//div[@data-name="make"]*

Comment: after writing Abarth in the filter box, i am trying to select it.... so im writing this xpath.. select_make_ele = WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//li[contains(@class,"multiselect-facets-item border-bottom"]/span[@class="icon-tick"]'))).click() 
but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Maybe try to use this --> //label[text()="Abarth"]
And that click on search button --> //a[text()="Search"]